# What is the correct way to pattern match nested lists?

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

I have the following function:

```
f[lst_List /; MatchQ[lst, SOME PATTERN HERE]] := 
  ({#[[1]] + #[[2]], #[[1]] - #[[2]]} &) /@ lst;
```

I want to match lists that are ordered pairs of reals: `{{0.1, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.4}}`, and so on.  I tried the following pattern:

```
MatchQ[{{0.1, 0.2},{0.3, 0.4}}, _List[_List[_Real, _Real]]]
```

but this returned `False`.  I know that:

```
MatchQ[{{0.1, 0.2},{0.3, 0.4}}, {__List}]
```

returns `True`, but this pattern is not sufficiently specific, since it also matches `{{}}`, among others.

What is the correct way to construct the pattern I want?

Comment: `MatchQ[{{0.1, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.4}},  List[List[_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ] ..]]` ?

Comment: `MatchQ[{{0.1, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.4}}, {{Except[_Complex], Except[_Complex]} ..}]`

Comment: Thank you very much.  They work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly refer to `MatchQ`. *Mathematica*'s pattern language is up to expressing what you want as an argument pattern.

```
f[lst : {{Repeated[Except[_Complex, _?NumberQ], {2}]} ..}] := 
  ({#[[1]] + #[[2]], #[[1]] - #[[2]]}&) /@ lst
f @ {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.4}, {1/2, 1}, {2, 2.}}
```

> ```
> {{0.3, -0.1}, {0.7, -0.1}, {3/2, -(1/2)}, {4., 0.}}
> ```

The function does not evaluate for lists containing pairs having a complex component.

```
f @ {{1, 1}, {1, I}}
```

> ```
> f[{{1, 1}, {1, I}}]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

It is not defined in the question what you wish to consider "real" for the purpose of this pattern.  Is `Pi` real for your purposes for example?  If you want to match only explicit decimal values you should use `_Real`, e.g. `{{_Real, _Real} ..}`.  If you want something more general I propose:

```
realQ = Re[#] == # &;
```

Because [`Re`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Re.html) is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) this can be applied to arrays, allowing:

```
f[lst : {{_, _} ..}?realQ] := (* body *)
```

This is clear, concise, and has lower overhead than what m_goldberg proposed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation.